# running an old django project on a new database

Tags: python, django

I have a django project code, there are 10 applications in it, and about 50 models that have relationships (foreign keys) with each other. There are no migration files.
I need to run this project. The database is empty.
Tell me, pls, what should be my steps for the correct launch of the project?
Are the following commands sufficient?

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py runserver
```

Comment: That looks standard - if things do not go well, you always have the chance to retry as many times as you like a number of different ways.

Answer (score 0):

Try migrating each app one by one. Like

```
python manage.py makemigrations [app_name]
python manage.py migrate [app_name]
```